# How to prevent hazelcast MapStore to put into IMAP old versions of Objects?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

If you have members of a cluster with old versions of one object  (*old libraries, unupdated objects, etc..*)  you could have into an IMAP duplicate entries ( from a point of view of a model object ) due to an incorrect management of libraries...

If you haven an IMAP, for example,  `IMAP<MyKey, MyValue>`  , different versions of *MyKey*,*MyValue* could be mixed...

1. When you do a GET of an old version of an object , you get a
   HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.InvalidClassException
2. When you do a PUT u don't get any exception ?....:(

Any way to control this?

Thank u!

Answer (score 3):

This really depends of how you serialize your objects.

- If you are relying on default java serialization (`MyKey` and `MyValue` implement `Serializable`), than your need to use `static final long serialVersionUID` and update it upon each modification of the class.
- If you are using custom serialization (for example implementing com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializer), than it is up to you to detect the format change on both read and write and act accordingly.

Note: if you need a more specific answer, please provide some code of your classes (`MyKey` and `MyValue`), hazelcast conf of the map in question and your serialization technique.

**EDIT (after comment):**

I am going to suppose that you a using the default `in-memory-format` for your map, which is `BINARY`. In this case, hazelcast, stores the items of the map as bytes without deserializing them, hence no exception on `put()`. However, when you `get()` the value, hazelcast has to deserialize it, and this is when you get the exception.

If on the other hand, you set `in-memory-format` to `OBJECT`, hazelcast will be forced to deserialize the object on `put()` and you are going to have the exception then.

**EDIT2:**

There is another way to provoke the exception on `put()` without changing the `in-memory-format`. You can add an `EntryAddedListener` on the map.

```
hz.getMap(Client.MAP_NAME).addEntryListener(new EntryAddedListener() {       
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent event) {
        // this will deserialize the new value and throw exception if format doesn't match
        event.getValue(); 
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: I am using Serializable, and serialVersionUID . But what about if there are differente versions on remote nodes?  I have experienced tht, to create (put) element there is no exception thrown...but is thrown to get.  I think if you put in a IMAP definied <MyKey, MyValue> , if different versions of objects are put should throw any exception.....

Comment: @Azimuts Edited my answer in response to your additional information